# URL Rewrite to choose from 2 differant extentions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have trying to achieve a url rewrite which can be fairly simple but i am unable to figure it out, here is what i want:
i have 2 files

test.html
test.php

my url request is test.html
my htacess rule should return the test.html file , and if test.html file doesnt exists then it should return test.php , the url stays the same i.e. test.html
so in short i want to check if the html file exists then return html file and if it doesnt then return php file.

Any help will be appreciated..  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really just do this with default document in Apache no mod_rewrite needed. If you set `test.html` as the higher priority document it will get chosen if they are both there otherwise `test.php` will be used if it is the only one there.

If you insist on doing this in mod_rewrite the following will work for you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteRule ^test\.html$              test.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Excellent,, thanks
dnt have access to apache so this the right solution for me.

Comment: how can i generalize it?

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC,L]`